# Using Bundler with :path option in gemfile in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I am working on a rails app which uses a gem also in development.  In my rails app, I have

```
gem 'somegem', :path => '~/r/somegem'
```

However, when I make changes to the code in somegem it does not update in my rails app.  I'm not sure which bundler commands I should be using after making changes, or if I need to at all.  Restarting the rails app doesn't help either.

Any suggestions on developing rails app with bundler and the :path option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command:

```
bundle install
```

This command evaluates your Gemfile and installs all missing dependencies. It will re-package your gem from that location and make it available via `bundle exec` next time you use it.

Also, be sure to start the server with:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

to be sure you're using your bundle's gems.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was doing what you said, but the issue was with sprockets.  The gem was a template engine, and because the input file wasn't touched, rails pulled the cached version.  Updating the file or deleting the cache helped.  This was in the dev environment- I'll need to look into always regenerating assets on every request.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the bundler webpage, don't forget to add the needed require at the top of your  code when using :path.

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```